# Oracle SQL TO_CHAR returning incorrect meridian indicators

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I'm trying to order some times by descending order. I've used the TO_CHAR function to extract the times from their date, 12hr with a meridian indicator. However, my results aren't what I'd expect - there are AMs mixed in with my PMs.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SAMPLETIME, 'HH:MI:SS AM') AS Time_Checked
ORDER BY Time_Checked DESC;
```

Here's a sample of the results I'm getting:

```
Time Checked
-------------
12:56:24 PM
12:56:24 PM
12:56:24 PM
12:56:24 PM
12:56:24 PM
12:56:24 PM
12:56:24 AM
12:56:24 AM
12:56:24 AM
12:56:24 AM
12:56:24 AM
12:56:24 AM
12:51:28 PM
12:51:28 PM
12:51:28 PM
12:51:28 PM
12:51:28 PM
12:51:28 PM
12:51:24 AM
12:51:24 AM
12:51:24 AM
12:51:24 AM
12:51:24 AM
12:51:24 AM
```

I expect the duplicate times, since this is coming from a database that makes continuous checks on lag times. It's giving me an equal amount of AMs to PMs. I expect the sample results to be in PM only, since I'm doing this in the afternoon.

Any ideas on why this is happening? When I changed to 24hr it worked fine.

Comment: There is no constraint on your select statement, so you are selecting all records in your table.  Are there AM records in the table?

Comment: You're ordering by the formatted string. You might want to `order by SAMPLETIME desc` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are sorting a string and not date.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SAMPLETIME, 'HH:MI:SS AM') AS Time_Checked
ORDER BY SAMPLETIME DESC;
```